# The XAML Designer has unexpectedly exited. (Exit code: 80008093)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I created a WPF application using .NET 6 in VS2022, but the designer is not working and displays the message: "The XAML Designer has unexpectedly exited. (Exit code: 80008093)"

I haven't made any changes to this application, as it's a new project. I've tried downloading the .NET 6 SDK and runtime, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Run "Clean" followed by a "Rebuild". If this doesn't help create a new Solution. Given you really have started a blank solution and changed nothing like moving or renaming projects and only added a blank project, this error could indicate a corrupted environment. If creating a blank solution doesn't help maybe repairing Visual Studio helps. Just google the error code and look what you can find. Also check the Windows log if you can find more detailed information about the exception. This should point you in the correct direct and you can refine your Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the root cause of this issue. It was due to the installation of certain encryption software on the company's computer. After setting up a whitelist, the issue was resolved.